# return a row where none exists when joining

Tags: sql, transactions

I have a transaction table that contains a transaction date, transaction total and a credit card id.  I'm joining this transaction table to a cardtype table that has a credit card id and the credit card type--this table only contains 4 rows with credit card types of Visa, Master Card, Discover and American Express.

I would like to view all transaction dates, totals and credit card types for every date and where but I would like a row to return for all dates and credit card types even if no transaction was made with a specific credit card type (ie I would like 4 rows to return for Sep 1 even if there were no transactions made with a Visa credit card).

A right join won't work because all 4 credit card types are used on various dates. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sub-query that returns a cross-product of all transaction dates and credit card types, and then LEFT JOIN that with the transactions:

```
SELECT c.txn_date txn_date, card_type, SUM(txn_total) daily_total
FROM (SELECT card_id, card_type, txn_date
      FROM cardtype
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT txn_date FROM transaction) t) c
LEFT JOIN transaction t
ON t.card_id = c.card_id AND t.txn_date = c.txn_date
GROUP BY c.card_id, txn_date
ORDER BY txn_date, card_type
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6308b/1)

Comment: Isn't SELECT card_id, card_type, txn_date
      FROM cardtype
      JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT txn_date FROM transaction) t  missing what it joins on?  I would need to add cardtypeid to the select distinct txn_date from transaction....

Comment: It's not joining on anything, it's creating a complete cross-product.

Comment: Okay, but I'm getting an error when trying to run it because of incorrect syntax near the ) after t....

Comment: I just fixed an ambiguous column, but I'm not getting a syntax error. See my fiddle.